# Parse custom date format into internal MYSQL format using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got dates being generated which look lke these:

Sun May 16 23:59:59 GMT 2011

I want to convert them into storable MYSQL form and so that i can read/compare them via php. I am using php. How can i convert the above into something MYSQL will understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# make an array
$bits = preg_split('/\s/', 'Sun May 16 23:59:59 GMT 2011');

# YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS is mySQL datetime format
$mysql_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$bits[1] $bits[2] $bits[5] $bits[3]"));
echo $mysql_datetime;
```

This parses your date format and turns it into proper mysql datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's internal [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function will parse the date into a unix timestamp. From there, you can either just store the timestamp, or use a quick [PHP function](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Unix-Timestamp-To-MySQL-Timestamp.html) to turn it into a date object that MySQL can store.

Or you can use MySQL's [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to get a date format.

Note: `strtotime` may not bode perfectly with your custom format. You may have to manually edit the string yourself to get a format that works with PHP's parsing function, which you can then follow the steps listed with.

Comment: a quick test shows that strtotime does NOT like his string at all -- it comes up with May 22, 2011. Whups.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it also reports 19:59:59 as the time, instead of 23:59:59. strtotime isn't perfect, and he'll probably have to parse it manually, or at the very least convert it into something the function understands. The other two steps (after you have a valid unix stamp) will still apply.